# formatted string to date conversion without changing format in java

Tags: java

I have formatted date in the form of string and i want it in date format without changing formatted pattern

here is my code

```
Date currDate = new Date();//Fri Oct 31 03:48:24 PDT 2014

    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    String formattedDate= formatter.format(currDate);//2014-10-31 04:23:42
```

here am getting in "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" format and the same format i want it in date.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
 Date paidDate = sdf.parse(formattedDate);

System.out.println(pattern + " " + paidDate);//Fri Oct 31 03:48:24 PDT 2014
```

but i am getting result as Fri Oct 31 03:48:24 PDT 2014, so pls help me to get result as 2014-10-31 04:23:42 in date format

Comment: Why don't you use `formatter.format(currDate)` in your `System.out.println` statement?

Comment: Change your pc default date format what you want and then `System.out.println(new Date())`http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12547_01/books/Sales_AppsConfigV1.2/Sales_AppsConfig_SalesProspector11.html

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your problem correctly:

```
System.out.println(pattern + " " + sdf.format(paidDate);
```

Comment: but it gives u in string, i want it in date

Comment: But you print string that represents date, not a date object

Comment: that date i have to store in database in date format

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be under the mistaken impression that a `Date` object somehow encodes format of the original date.  It doesn't.

So ... when you do this:

```
Date paidDate = sdf.parse(formattedDate);
```

it does not "remember" original format of the text form of the date in `paidDate`.  And it cannot.  If you want to print / unparse a Date in any format than the default one, you should use a `DateFormat` and call its `format` method.  Calling `toString()` will just give you the date in the default format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

System.out.println(formatter.format(paidDate));

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Do not conflate a date-time object with a string representing its value. A date-time object has no “format”.

```
ZonedDateTime.now(                                         // Instantiate a `ZonedDateTime` object capturing the current moment.
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )                            // Assign this time zone through which we see the wall-clock time used by the people of this particular region.
).format(                                                  // Generate a string representing the value of this `ZonedDateTime` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" )   // Define a formatting pattern to match your desire.
)
```

> 2018-03-10 07:36:23

Calling `ZonedDateTime::toString` generates a string in standard ISO 8601 format.

> 2018-03-10T07:36:23.595362+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

## Date-time object has no “format”

You are confusing a date-time object in Java, or a date-time value stored in a database, with a textual representation. You can generate a string from a date-time object (or database value), but that string is separate and distinct from the value it represents. Do not conflate a string with its generating creator.

## java.time

Avoid using the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`. Instead, use `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`, and `DateTimeFormatter` classes, respectively.

If you have an input string such as `2014-10-31 04:23:42`, replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with ISO 8601 standard format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
String input = "2014-10-31 04:23:42".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

That input lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So parse as a `LocalDateTime` which purposely lacks any concept of zone/offset.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2014-10-31T04:23:42

A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. To determine an actual moment, you must supply the context of a zone or offset.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;  // Now we have an actual moment, a point on the timeline.
```

To capture the current moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Adjust into another zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-03-10T07:36:23.595362+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

I do not recommend generating strings lacking an indicator of zone/offset. But if you insist, use the built-in `DateTimeFormatter` and then replace the `T` in the middle with a SPACE to get your desired format.

```
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ).replace( "T" , " " ) ;
```

> 2018-03-10 07:36:23.595362

If you really do not want the fractional second, then define your own formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ) ; 
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> 2018-03-10 07:36:23

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).